# Can we find a linear functional $f$ such that $f(y_0)=1$ and $f(z)=0$ on $\overline{R(A)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector spaces and $Y$ be a topological vector space. Let $A:V\to Y$ be a linear map. If $R(A)=Range\,space\,of\,A $ is not closed and if $Y$ is Hausdorff and locally convex, then for any $y_0\notin \overline{R(A)}$

Can we find a linear functional $f$ such that $f(y_0)=1$ and $f(z)=0$ on $\overline{R(A)}$ ?

### Myself:

Hahn banach Theorem guarantees that,a  $f:Y\to \mathbb K$ exists such that,
$f(y_0)=d(y_0, \overline{R(A)}) $ and $||f||=1$.
But from this, can I try that??

Comment: If $Y$ is just a topological vector space, neither $\lVert f\rVert$ for $f \colon Y \to \mathbb{K}$ nor $d(y_0,\overline{R(A)})$ are defined. I suppose you want $f$ to be continuous (otherwise, linear algebra takes you home). But Hahn-Banach says you have a continuous $f_0$ with $f_0(y_0) \neq 0$ and $\overline{R(A)}\subset \ker f_0$. Then $f = \frac{1}{f_0(y_0)}\cdot f_0$ is your friend.

Comment: I am sorry..I could not understand your arguments... will that $f$ satisfy my requirements??@DanielFischer